# How to exit blackberry application properly when blackberry OS shows permission alert for camera and user clicks call end (Red) button

Tags: java, blackberry, barcode, barcode-scanner

We developed an application which decodes QR code using Blackberry BarcodeScanner class on OS 6 and above. When barcode scanner screen is invoked, OS alerts for camera permission and application is obscured i.e. it goes in the background. On this point, if user clicks red call end button, application hides (it remains in background and does not terminate) and alert remains open. On accepting ALLOW or DENY and re-opening application, mobile gets hanged and need to be restarted by removing battery from device.

What I want to do is when user clicked red call end button in this situation, I can terminate the application entirely. As OS permission alert is independent from application, when user will invoke application, it will have that permission.

Please help me by telling how can I terminate application from that point.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why the application hangs, but the best solution is that you should be testing for the permissions you need at start up, using the [ApplicationPermissionManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html). If you don't have permissions that are critical for application function (the camera is critical to bar code scanning) then you should request the permission through the API which allows you to provide a reason the permission is required. This should happen before you request access to the controlled resource. If the critical permissions are not granted by the user you can display a message and exit cleanly.

For completeness, if the resource is not critical to appliction function the application should ask for the permission once, at first start up, and if not given permission disable the functionality that requires that permission.

Using the default permission request at the time the resource is needed is confusing to most users and does not match the permission granting methods used in more modern systems (BB10, iOS, Android) whereas asking for all the permissions you need on first start provides a better user experience and is easier to handle in the code.

Comment: I already tried to request permission at start up but it did'nt worked. Perhaps it asked the permission twice on starting barcode scanning. I think I am not doing it the right way. Can you please provide any sample code for that ? And Thanks for you reply and appreciate your response in this regard.

Comment: A more effecient path may be for you to post the code you used so other members can review it.